# What type is this autocomplete and how search query works on it

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

have a question about this kind of autocomplete.
How it works?!?

We use Google autocomplete, and Google library for adresses.
But in Google maps api we didnt found any option to change "pac-icon" only near Airport, and didnt found even customizable adress with own icon.

I wanna ask more clever people, how those autocomplete works, what kinds of autocomplete they are and if its possible to do with google, before we will pay for premium at Google Maps Appi.

Thank You soo much for help !!

[Blacklane autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXCfi.jpg)

[myDriver autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCrfU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitations in Places API you can only set the pac-icon for all the results in the searchbox due to it being CSS class.

You can on the other hand restrict the search to Central Europe by different ways:

Option 1 - Setting the way by bounds, In this example I am telling it to limit the search between France and Czechia

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.144137,-2.4447717),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.7855718,13.2273027);

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
  bounds: defaultBounds
});
```

Option 2 - Restricting the search to a list of countries(5 max)

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

You can find more information and examples in the [Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox) for Maps Javascript API.

Comment: Hello Franco, thank you for your answer. One think solved and do sou know about autocomplete, those two websites use ? (Blackalne / myDriver) . Thank you sooo much for your help !

Comment: Hi thanks, for you reply but if you want truly show appreciation on StackOverflow you can upvote my answer. Cheers.